# Updating from MYSQL to MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So as MYSQL is deprecated and eveyone keeps telling me to update, I thought it was about time I did.

But as I'm not used to mysqli_*, it seems alien to me. And it's not a simple edit when I have a whole site coded in Mysql.

So I'm wondering: How would I transform the below code into Mysqli? Just to give me and anyone else a good starting point when dealing with querying the database.

```
$sql_follows="SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user1_id=".$_SESSION['id']." AND status=2 OR user2_id=".$_SESSION['id']." AND status=2";
$query_follows=mysql_query($sql_follows) or die("Error finding friendships");
if($query_follows>0){
}
```

**EDIT:** On reading up and editing my whole site the above code converted to MYSQLI_ would go something like this..

```
 $Your_SQL_query_variable= mysqli_query($connectionvariable,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user1_id=".$_SESSION['id']." AND status=2 OR user2_id=".$_SESSION['id']." AND status=2")) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
```

Comment: This post has a nice example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: As a sidenote, now that you're switching to MySQLi you should use prepared statements instead of string concatenation for adding specific values to your SQL. Else you might get a visit from [little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Ya just can beat using models; think of how easy it would be if you had a methods like `$model->get_friendships($_SESSION['id']);`, time for some refactoring....

Comment: How does your method work @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can download a converter tool from here:

https://github.com/philip/MySQLConverterTool

The code it generates is pretty gross, mainly because of the way it implements the default database link argument with a `$GLOBAL` variable. (This also makes it easy to recognize when someone is using code that's gone through the converter.)

There's also a MySQL Shim Library located here:

https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim

Comment: Fantastic. I've just completed converting before seeing this..But this will help in the future and for anyone else also converting.

Comment: @Barmar. I am searching everywhere for the mirror as the link on the page above is dead. Do you know where I can find it now?Thanks.

Comment: @BernardA Google found a GitHub repository.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to transform is to look at the php reference library. Very easy to use and will tell you everything you need to know:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php