# Convert mysql to mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to change my code to `mysqli`, I heard `mysql` isn't recommended and  I'm having trouble changing my code to `mysqli`.

I managed to connect to my database but the rest of the code doesn't seem to work, I tried changing all `mysql` to `mysqli` but it didn't work. What could I do so the code works the same but in `mysqli`?

Could someone rewrite it so I could see the difference. I haven't seen any good tutorials.

```
<?php
 $db = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'searchengine');

    if($db->connect_errno) {
        die('sorry we are having some problbems');
        }

$sql = mysql_query(sprintf(
    "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE pagecontent LIKE '%s' LIMIT 0,%d",
        '%'. mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']) .'%',
        mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['results']))
);

while($ser = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<h2><a href='$ser[pageurl]'>$ser[pageurl]</a></h2>";
}

mysql_close();
```

Comment: Your main problem appears to be that you're still using *mysql* functions like `mysql_query()`, `mysql_real_escape_string()` and `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020227/updating-from-mysql-to-mysqli

Comment: @Phil That's because he hasn't done the rewrite, he's asking us to do it for him.

Comment: You're mixing two types of MySQL functions. You start off with one, (*the "good" one*), then you're using the deprecated version. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and troubleshoot it from there.

Comment: @Barmar Well, he started off in the right direction with `new mysqli()`

Comment: @Barmar That link you gave, should have been marked with as being a duplicate, using it to vote to close.

Comment: I wasn't sure -- It's mostly a pointer to a tool that automates it, but it's not really a great tool.

Comment: @Barmar Urgh, not that Oracle tool I hope. That thing is awful

Comment: That's my point. I used it once a couple of years ago, the resulting code was a mess. But if you have a huge amount of code to convert, the choice may be between a mess and not doing it at all.

Comment: Either way, this question is what Barmar also stated, asking "us" to do the work. I'm voting to close as unclear. It's already been asked more times than I can remember. (Actually, voted as ***primarily opinion-based***), because that's exactly what's going to happen, one will use prepared statements, and another PDO etc.

Comment: The documentation is your friend: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
 $db = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'searchengine');

    if($db->connect_errno) {
        die('sorry we are having some problbems');
        }

$sql = $db->query(sprintf(
    "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE pagecontent LIKE '%s' LIMIT 0,%d",
        '%'. $db->real_escape_string($_GET['term']) .'%',
        $db->real_escape_string($_GET['results']))
);

while($ser = $sql->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<h2><a href='" . $ser['pageurl'] . "'>" . $ser['pageurl'] . "</a></h2>";
}

$db->close();
```

Comment: Change `$ser[pageurl]` to `$ser['pageurl']` to prevent warnings.

Comment: @Phil Legitimate, but it will throw warnings if you don't suppress (bad idea).

Comment: I changed it to concatenation just for cleanliness. Better to tick your array vars anyways

Comment: @OPatel No, it won't. Does nobody read the manual anymore :(. This is perfectly fine and triggers no warnings or notices - `"Array keys in strings like $arr[key] do not need to be quoted"`

Comment: `$sql->fetch_array($sql)` this line will not work, because you're mixing up contexts. When calling fetch_array in this manner, you don't have to pass $sql as a parameter. Doing so will cause an error.

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't have been there. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the answer of @Machavity who's using a object oriented style you can use a procedural style as well:

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '', 'searchengine');

    if(!$db) {
        die('sorry we are having some problems');
    }

    $sql = mysqli_query(
        $db,
        sprintf(
            "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE pagecontent LIKE '%s' LIMIT 0,%d",
            '%'. mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['term']) .'%',
            mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['results'])
        )
    );

    while($ser = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "<h2><a href='$ser[pageurl]'>$ser[pageurl]</a></h2>";
    }

    mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: This works as well, but I recommend using object oriented style to prevent stringy code.

Comment: You do realise the procedural style global namespace functions are just wrappers for the OO methods, right?

Comment: @Phil - Yes, but still it is a different **style**.