# Update mysql function to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to update this code to be mysqli, but dont know where to begin.
I know that the connection is handled like this , buts thats as far as iv got.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'admin', 'admin', 'database_name');
```

Function to be updated:

```
$cn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin', 'admin') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('database_name',$cn) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM category";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<select>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    echo "<option value='".$row["name"]."'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
    }mysql_free_result($rs);
    echo "</select>";
```

---

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT name FROM category');
echo "<select>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value='".$row["name"]."'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
}mysql_free_result($sql);
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: It is nice that we have great manuals on http://php.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating from MYSQL to MYSQLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020227/updating-from-mysql-to-mysqli)

Answer (score 0):

```
$cn=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'admin', 'admin','database_name') or die(mysqli_error($cn));
$sql = "SELECT name FROM category";
$rs = mysqli_query($cn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($cn));
echo "<select>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
echo "<option value='".$row["name"]."'>".$row["name"]."</option>";
}mysqli_free_result($rs);
echo "</select>";
```

You can learn about mysqli on PHP's website [Mysqli Book](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

But for security and other benefits you should now use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead