# While loop print additional empty line

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have the following `while` loop, which I used to create a drop-list select containing date fetched from database:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM persons";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
```

The while loop prints an additional empty line into the drop list, i.e. there is an empty line appearing in the list.  How can I avoid that?

Comment: Minor side-note: If the value is the same as the displayed text, you can omit the `value` attribute - it will default to the displayed text. `<option>John Smith</option>` will yield "John Smith" as its value.

Comment: Voted to close - there is a `NULL` or `empty` record in your db.

Comment: Stop using MySQL, [start using MySQLi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020227/updating-from-mysql-to-mysqli) . You will live to enjoy the change :-)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in this code prints an empty option. Are you sure you don't have a record in your database where name is NULL or empty?

Try adding

```
WHERE name IS NOT NULL and name != ""
```

to your query

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have empty row in your results from the database. You can check the persons table for this or you could fix it in the code by doing something like the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM persons";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!empty($row['name'])) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";

    }
}
```

Comment: This will still print an empty option since isset() will return true as the value may be an empty string. You should use !empty() instead

Comment: Doh wasn't paying attention. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use PHP empty function like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM persons";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         if(!empty($row['name']))
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
        }
}
```